# Manage a matrix row(python3)

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, matrix, row

So I have this code to input a matrix:

```
matrix = []
        loop = True
        while loop:
            line = input()
            if not line: 
                loop = False
                values = line.split()
                row = [int(value) for value in values]
                matrix.append(row)
```

Now I want to manage a row in the matrix;so fair I did this:

```
def row_management(matrix):

   theline = int(input('wich line?'))
   thelist = [matrix[theline-1]]
   modified_line = list_menu(thelist)
   matrix[theline-1] = modified_line
```

However,if I try to find the max or min of the matrix row by doing

```
max(theline)  or min(theline)
```

It always result an empty list []

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is a little off. Your matrix is just a list, so you should not indent until you reach your loop. Secondly, it looks like you are never writing anything to your matrix in your while loop because it only tries to insert values when line is False. I modified your code slightly, which should now populate your data. I'm not really following your function or how you are trying to call the min and max values, but I think your main issue is populating your matrix:

```
matrix = []
loop = True
while loop:
    line = input()
    if line: 
        values = line.split()
        row = [int(value) for value in values]
        matrix.append(row)
    else:
        loop = False
```